# Camel Component: setting a Property dynamically from a Bean

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have defined a Camel Route in a Jboss Fuse BluePrint. I'd need to set one variable at runtime from a Bean. See this example:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
     <route id="wsClient">
            <from uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
            <setBody>
                <simple>Message</simple>
            </setBody>
            <transform>
                  <method bean="myBean" method="transform" />
            </transform>
            <to uri="cxf:bean:MyWebService?defaultOperationName={{operation}}" />
            <to uri="mock:result" />
     </route>
</camelContext>
```

In this example, I'd like to set the property named "**operation**" within the bean "myBean". Is it possible to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. 
First, set a header from the bean and later use http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

I am not familiar with Spring DSL, but in Java DSL it would look like this:

```
.recipientList(simple("cxf:bean:MyWebService?defaultOperationName=${header.operation}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that inside the bean. No need to pass any specific parameter. Camel  can bind the exchange, body...etc as a method parameter automatically. Ref: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

using below code you can set the header or property

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("HeaderName", "Value");

exchange.setProperty("Key", "Value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply which seems promising. The only limit is that some of my Beans do not implement the Exchange pattern, I mean they are just Java POJO which receive as parameter a Web service parameter. So in other words they receive in input a Java Object instead of the Exchange. Is it possible to inject the Exchange object also in the pure Java Bean ? Thanks a lot